# three js bounding box of all world objects

Tags: three.js

Does threejs keep or can it generate a bounding box for all objects??

Anyone know of a easy way to get the two points which would represent the bounding box of all objects in the world?

Need the bounding box of all object in WORLD space, so if a long object has been rotated I'd like to find the bounding box of the world taking into account the rotation of that object.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d

Answer (score 0):

Bounding boxes come from Geometries. You could find the bounding box of your "top" or root objects, and calculate the minimum and the maximum points of these bounding boxes. That would give you the "world" bounding box.