# Any way to get a bounding box from a three.js Object3D?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm loading an OBJ file using Three.js and OBJLoader.js.  This returns a Three.Object3D object, which has what you'd expect from a 3D model (position vector, up vector...)

What I can't figure out is how to get a bounding box for it-- is this possible?

Answer (score 115):

You don't need to iterate over all children of the object; there's a method in the library to do this: `THREE.Box3#setFromObject`: [see the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3). For example, you can do:

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
```

to get the bounding box of `obj`, including all of its children, and accounting for any translations, rotations, etc.

Note that the `BoundingBox` helper is intended to draw a bounding box in the scene, not for just calculating the bounding box of some object.

Comment: this the best answer here

Comment: thanks for this great and concise answer. Just wanted to point out that the link to the docs changed to [see the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3) though

Comment: This answer is good, but can be inefficient. This function retraverse the whole hierarchy, as well as all the vertices. A good idea would be to call `geometry.computeBoundingBox()` on all meshes, and create a function that expand the main bounding box using all the scene bounding boxes.

Answer (score 35):

If you want the bounding box position and size *as the object appears in the scene*, try the BoundingBoxHelper:

```
var helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(someObject3D, 0xff0000);
helper.update();
// If you want a visible bounding box
scene.add(helper);
// If you just want the numbers
console.log(helper.box.min);
console.log(helper.box.max);
```

The `.boundingBox` on the geometry doesn't account for translations, rotations, or scaling that may be applied to the parent mesh and etc. and I found it very difficult to adjust for that manually, but the helper does it for you.

Comment: Note that _BoundingBoxHelper_ has been [deprecated](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10143), and superseded by [BoxHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/helpers/BoxHelper).

Answer (score 21):

For any shape, on its geometry object, there is a `boundingBox` property. This property holds a `THREE.Box3` object. This `Box3` object consists of two `THREE.Vector3` objects, `min` and `max`.

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(...);
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(...);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

var boundingBox = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.clone();
alert('bounding box coordinates: ' + 
    '(' + boundingBox.min.x + ', ' + boundingBox.min.y + ', ' + boundingBox.min.z + '), ' + 
    '(' + boundingBox.max.x + ', ' + boundingBox.max.y + ', ' + boundingBox.max.z + ')' );
```

For more complex shapes, like those loaded from [JSON Object files](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Object-Scene-format-4), the bounding box property is undefined by default. It must be computed explicitly.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load(imagePath, function(object){

    geometry = object.children[0].children[0].geometry;  // substitute the path to your geometry

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();  // otherwise geometry.boundingBox will be undefined

    var boundingBox = geometry.boundingBox.clone();
    alert('bounding box coordinates: ' + 
        '(' + boundingBox.min.x + ', ' + boundingBox.min.y + ', ' + boundingBox.min.z + '), ' + 
        '(' + boundingBox.max.x + ', ' + boundingBox.max.y + ', ' + boundingBox.max.z + ')' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jodes.  However I'm still not clear how/if I can get a bounding box for the `Object3D` class itself.  Do I need to walk through all its children and look for `Mesh` types, save their bounding boxes and compare and compute the maximum x/y/z values that way?

Comment: If you want to perform e.g. mouse-picking, you use the values from `geometry.boundingBox` and create your own box similar to this: `var box = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(width, height, depth), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color : 0xFFF0FF }) );` I tend to attach this to the `Object3D` or `Mesh` in question. You can then raycast against that object or perform collisions (or whatever).

Answer (score 13):

Yes you would need something like this:

```
if (object instanceof THREE.Object3D)
{
    object.traverse (function (mesh)
    {
        if (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        {
            mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox ();
            var bBox = mesh.geometry.boundingBox;

            // compute overall bbox
            minX = Math.min (minX, bBox.min.x);
            minY = Math.min (minY, bBox.min.y);
            minZ = Math.min (minZ, bBox.min.z);
            maxX = Math.max (maxX, bBox.max.x);
            maxY = Math.max (maxY, bBox.max.y);
            maxZ = Math.max (maxZ, bBox.max.z);
        }
    });

    var bBox_min = new THREE.Vector3 (minX, minY, minZ);
    var bBox_max = new THREE.Vector3 (maxX, maxY, maxZ);
    var bBox_new = new THREE.Box3 (bBox_min, bBox_max);

    scene.add (object);
}
```

**EDIT:**

This method is before the `BoundingBoxHelper()` or `BoxHelper()` were available

Comment: I would just like to add that you may want to do something like minX = Math.min (minX, bBox.min.x + mesh.position.x ); for computing the overall box, just in case some of the children of the object have been placed at locations other than ( 0 , 0 , 0 )

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for