# Bounding Box of a stl object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box

Good day everyone,

I have come across several posts about this topic but no solution would work. I have an object that I load with the help of the STLLoader in three.js for which I would like to get a bounding box.

```
    // Add stl objects and a name
function addSTLObject(url, name) {
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load(url, function (geometry) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff5533 });
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        // To scale element, use:
        // mesh.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        // Add a name to the object to find it if it needs to be removed
        mesh.name = name;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.z = 0;

        scene.add(mesh);
    });
}
```

and I am loading this object as follows:

```
addSTLObject('model/cases/iphone5.stl', 'phone-model');
var phoneModelAdded = scene.getObjectByName('phone-model', true);
```

Now I have tried the solutions provided here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3471 and here [Any way to get a bounding box from a three.js Object3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d)

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(phoneModelAdded);

var geometry = phoneModel.children[0].children[0].geometry;
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
```

While the first solution gives me an error saying "Cannot read property 'updateMatrixWorld' of undefined", the second gives me no error at all but does nothing and if I try accessing the "geometry" property it says that it doesn't exist.

Does someone have a working solution?
Any help is appreciated.

Have a good day!

**EDIT**:

```
        // Add stl objects and a name
function addSTLObject(url, name) {
    var bbox;
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load(url, function (geometry) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff5533 });
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        // To scale element, use:
        // mesh.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        // Add a name to the object to find it if it needs to be removed
        mesh.name = name;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.z = 0;

        bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);

        scene.add(mesh);

        return bbox;
    });
}
```

and aftwards

```
var bbox = addSTLObject('model/cases/iphone5.stl', 'phone-model');
    scene.add(bbox);
```

Error: "THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D"

**EDIT 2:**

```
var bbox, bboxComputed = false;

    function addSTLObject(url, name) {
    var bbox;
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load(url, function (geometry) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff5533 });
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        // To scale element, use:
        // mesh.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        // Add a name to the object to find it if it needs to be removed
        mesh.name = name;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.z = 0;

        bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(mesh);
        bbox.update();
        bboxComputed = true;

        scene.add(mesh);
    });

}

addSTLObject('model/cases/iphone5.stl', 'phone-model');
    var myInterval = setInterval( function(){
        if( bboxComputed ) {
            alert( bbox.box.min, bbox.box.max, bbox.box.size() );
            scene.add(bbox);
            clearInterval( myInterval );
            bboxComputed = false;
        }
    }, 100 );
```

This won't work.

**EDIT 3:**
I was trying to set up a function that would have everything I need and give back an object with all of the calculated information:

```
    function calculateSTLProperties(url, name) {
    var STLObject, STLbbox, STLComputed = false, STLGeometry;

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load(url, function (geometry) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff5533 });
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        // To scale element, use:
        // mesh.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        // Add a name to the object to find it if it needs to be removed
        mesh.name = name;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.z = 0;

        // Compute a bounding box for the element
        STLbbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(mesh);
        STLbbox.update();

        // Get the geometry of the case
        STLGeometry = geometry;
        STLComputed = true;
    });

    // Set an interval to wait for the corresponding bounding box and geometry to be computed
    var myInterval = setInterval( function(){
        if( STLComputed ) {
        STLObject = {
            "geometry" : STLGeometry,
            "bbox" : STLbbox,
            "x" : STLbbox.box.size().x,
            "y" : STLbbox.box.size().y,
            "z" : STLbbox.box.size().z
        };

        clearInterval( myInterval );
        bboxComputed = false;

        }
    }, 100 );

    return STLObject;
}
```

Unfortunately, somehow the object doesn't get passed through and I end up with an "undefined" in the end when trying to save it:

```
var STLObjectLoaded = calculateSTLProperties('model/cases/iphone5.stl', 'phone-model');
    console.log(STLObjectLoaded);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know that the object has actually been loaded before you call `scene.getObjectByName()`. Loading is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model loading is asynchronous so all you computations should happen after the model has loaded. Add a callback, which is called when the model has loaded and add there the call to the bbox. The way you have it the `scene.getObjectByName()` call is being made with an empty object which you also verify ("if I try accessing the "geometry" property it says that it doesn't exist")

**Update:**

Use:

```
var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( mesh ); bbox.update();
scene.add( bbox );
```

from inside the `loader.load()` function.

The `setFromObject()` call only create the bounding box but not the geometry for the bbox.

**Update II**

If you want the `bbox` to be available outside your `loader.load()` function you would need to use a global variable

```
var bboxComputed = false;
```

which you set to true right after you compute the bbox inside your `loader.load()` function:

```
scene.add( bbox );
bboxComputed = true;
```

Then in your main instead of using:

```
console.log( bbox.box.min, bbox.box.max, bbox.box.size() );
```

you would use something like:

```
var myInterval = setInterval( function(){
    if( bboxComputed ) {
        console.log( bbox.box.min, bbox.box.max, bbox.box.size() );
        clearInterval( myInterval );
    }
}, 100 );
```

I am setting a delay of 0.1 second and when the `bbox` has finally been computed I clear the interval so that it does not run forever.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I call my function, I call `.getObjectByName()` and then I call `var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(phoneModelAdded);`. So this should be the right order shouldn't it?

How would I add a 'callback'?

Comment: Yes but call them inside the loader.load() callback.

Comment: I changed my post with what I changed and the resulting error. Help please!

Comment: the `return bbox` returns from `loader.load()` not from `addSTLObject()`

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately. Maybe looking at my setup will clear things: http://sebastianjvf.github.io/index2.html

Comment: what you are doing still falls victim of asynchronous loading as the `return bbox` from inside `addSTLObject()` will be a null object. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Last question: I would still need the bbox to be available outside the function. How can I achieve that without falling into asynchronous loading?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am confused. I get the idea but I don't really know how I would be able to access the information of the bbox? If I put the interval in the main section it wouldn't be known to the main, would it? I edited my post above!

Comment: sorry, you would make the variable `bbox` global.

Comment: That works perfectly! I thought it didn't work but I had a simple spelling error in one of my variables. Thank you so much!

Comment: I updated my post for the last time. Could you take a last look, please? Thank you! ("EDIT 3")

Answer (score 0):

As of three.js R125, the recommended way to do this is with the loadAsync method, which is now native to three.js:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync

That method returns a promise. You could then use a 'then' to get the geometry of the STL and create the mesh. You could also use a traditional callback as in earlier answers, or an async/await structure, but I think the example below using the native three.js method is the simplest way. The example shows how you can get geometry to a global variable once the promise is resolved and the STL file is loaded:

```
// Global variables for bounding boxes
let bbox;

const loader = new STLLoader();
const promise = loader.loadAsync('model1.stl');
promise.then(function ( geometry ) {
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  bbox = mesh.geometry.boundingBox;
  scene.add( mesh );
  buildScene();
  console.log('STL file loaded!');
}).catch(failureCallback);

function failureCallback(){
  console.log('Could not load STL file!');
}

function buildScene() {
  console.log('STL file is loaded, so now build the scene');
  // !VA bounding box of the STL mesh accessible now
  console.log(bbox);
  // Build the rest of your scene...
}
```