# Rendering a frame around a 3d object using opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rajawali

I am rendering a 3d Object using [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) and Opengl on android. I want to render a cube around boundaries of the object in exactly the same as shown.

I understand the I may need to use a set of lines or the [stack](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-18-Drawing-Lines) api in rajawali. But I dont understand how can I use the Object3D api to figure out which points consists of the line. I tried using Object3D.getGeometry().getBoundingBox() api but its returning null.

I need hints on how can I derive the min max Number3d points using Rajawali api and whether it would be the right solution to create a set of 12 lines based on those lines. Or should I somehow augment it into the Model after loading so that i can scale around with it?

This may be too obvious but please consider me a beginner. Thanks.

[image: 3DModel with a Frame Around it]

Answer (score 0):

`Object3D.getGeometry().getBoundingBox()` return undefined value until you call `Object3D.getGeometry().computeBoundingBox()` method which updates the bounding box information.

The Answer below will give you more information if you are using complex 3d objects with scene hierarchy. 
[Any way to get a bounding box from a three.js Object3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d)

Update:
The best way is to create a separate object with lines using Min/Max values and use the original object's Transformation. Or make the BoundingBox geometry a child for the original object.

Comment: Rajawali Library for Opengl does not have any method for computing Bounding Box. But even If I get it, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information. I just found that Object3D has a member variable mShowBoundingVolume. Check this source: https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/Object3D.java

Comment: Bounding box is null. So no hope of rendering that. Opened a issue https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/issues/1774

Comment: From their code, class files Geometry3D & BoundingBox: I looks like bounding box are calculated only if the Geometry is constructed using Vertices. If you are constructing the Geometry3D object directly from buffers, then the class is unable calculate BoundingBox.

Comment: That was helpful. Can you suggest a workaround ? I have already dived into how bounding box is created inside the library. Can I create vertices from BufferData? Or perhaps get min max vertices from BufferData?

Comment: The best way is to calculate the bouding box from the buffer you are sending to the class. Or feed vertices instead of buffer. Plz give more info on how you are getting the buffer from, so we can work on a solution.