# Threejs Json object loaded in network section but not able to load in threejs

Tags: json, object, three.js

i have been trying to load the json model with any of these loader

```
1)OBJLoader()
2)JSONLoader()
3)AssimpJSONLoader()
```

But in all case i am able to load the object but not able to see on the threejs scene.
Here is small section of my loading code

```
var loader2= new THREE.ObjectLoader();//new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader2.load( 'Models/bed.json', function ( object ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++) 
       {
        object.children[i].visible=true;
        object.children[i].material.color = 0xffb830;
      }
scene.add( object );
});
```

Problem is when i use the obj loader it will say use JSONLoader .when i use json loader it gives me error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

If you try to load the object given in the link you will get the whole picture.
Here is the link of my [object](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzUf69fddUPNbjVIU0UwdlU5MTA) .

I cant understand is it the issue with my json file loader or not
As the same file is being used by some other developer and use code like this

> THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.loadAjaxJSON

Any direction on the resolution to resolve issue will be welcome.

Comment: Firstly, try to add the bounding box to your object to determine it's position.More info here: [get a bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d)

Comment: On the same loop  i used the    -------->var boundingBoxHelperObject = new THREE.BoxHelper( objecttomove.children[i], 0x000000 );
 scene.add( boundingBoxHelperObject );

Comment: And do you see the bounding boxes?

Comment: yes when i use the other model and object loader.but when i use the model in the link and json loader the item is loaded in the network but gives error as mention on the question

Comment: It looks like your JSON is formatted in an odd manner. JSONLoader looks for an array of `faces`, not an array of `tris`, which is what your file has. You're getting `Cannot read property of 'length' of undefined` because the `faces` array does not exist in your file. What software did you use to export your JSON file?

Comment: This JSON looks unfamiliar to me, although i only have experience with the 3ds max json loader. I also think that the data is formatted oddly.

Comment: one of our old  frnd is using the same json along with other files to 1)make 2)set 3)lightning etc. and his entire thing is working but refuse to give details. i was wounding  what he has done.that we cant do