# How to get bounding box information from a 3D object in aframe?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am working on an aframe project that involves loading 3D objects of unknown sizes into my scene. Naturally I would want to resize the object to a certain size (like fixed height) before I put it in the scene. But how do I extract information like width, height and depth from the object's bounding box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use A-Frame's underlying three.js APIs here. That answer has [been posted for three.js before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d), but here's an A-Frame version:

```
// get three.js object from aframe entity
var el = document.querySelector('#my-element');
var object = el.getObject3D('mesh');

// compute bounding box
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
console.log(bbox.min, bbox.max)
```

Comment: I tried this method for pre-loaded 3D models, and it works great. But somehow when I try to .getObject3D('mesh') and then .setFromObject from a runtime loaded 3D model, I keep getting this error message: 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateMatrixWorld' of undefined
    at et.expandByObject (three.js:8020)
    at et.setFromObject (three.js:7932)
Which is complaining that .getObject3D('mesh') is returning undefined.

Comment: Ah! using THREE.OBJLoader() can get the right object with which a bounding box can be constructed. Still, got no idea why the runtime loaded obj model in aframe is not able to supply a correct Object3D.