# Display text inside 3D box using aframe /aframe-ar

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I do want to display some text inside 3D box image using aframe in ar.js.

Following is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/examples/vendor/aframe/build/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
        <!-- <script>THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = 'https://rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js/master/three.js/'</script> -->
    </head>
    <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best;'>
            <a-anchor hit-testing-enabled='true'>
                <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'>
                <a-entity text="value: HELLO"></a-entity>
            </a-box>
        </a-anchor>
        <a-camera-static/>
        </a-scene>

    </body>
</html>
```

My main task is to project some dynamic text inside the 3D box. But for instance, I am trying to put some static text. But unable to do so. Does anybody know how can I add text inside the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually Your code is working, but both the box, and text are white + the text is really small:

[image]

---

If You enlarge it a bit + make it black, it would be apparent, that it is there:

```
<a-entity position="1 0 0" scale="3 3 3" text="value: HELLO;color:black"></a-entity>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can we set the position of text? I want to display some key value like Name, email in each row at the front face of the square box.

Comment: @Vaidya You can throw there new lines using `\n` like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gt6Lvgqd/)

Comment: Last doubt I have is, As it is 3D obj and a square box have six sides. So, can we control on which side to display data? I want the data to be display on the side which is exactly in front of  Hiro Image (In the same way as Hiro is displayed in above image.). Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want it to face the camera, or always be on the same side of the cube ?

Comment: You could try and use [this](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/look-at/) component and make the box `look-at` the `<a-camera-static/>` but if it won't work then i'm afraid it's a bigger topic for another question

Comment: If it won't work I will display data n=in any static side. weather that side faces camera or not. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Vaidya if you want it to be exactly on the side of the cube, then get the bounding box (like Don McCurdy did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291812/how-to-get-bounding-box-information-from-a-3d-object-in-aframe)) and position the text on the side. If it doesn't have to be with a surgical precision, just create the scene without ar.js and change the position in the inspector to see which values satisfy your needs

Comment: Thank You @Piotr Adam Milewski. Now I got the clear view to complete the task!