# Aframe 0.8.0 not able to load some GLTF models

Tags: aframe

I have been using Aframe for making small applications.

I came across some models from poly that are not being loaded. Here are the links:

Model 1: Hill link: https://poly.google.com/view/biVS28j2w4g

GLTF 2.0 link: https://poly.googleusercontent.com/downloads/biVS28j2w4g/6OJLeYzlT9M/Hill.gltf

---

Model 2: Speaker link: https://poly.google.com/view/5AcolbPvaM9

GLTF Link: https://poly.googleusercontent.com/downloads/5AcolbPvaM9/blsDCJca0e7/Wall%20desk%20speakers.gltf

---

Model 3: Speaker 2.1 link: https://poly.google.com/view/3N5cUYDN30g

GLTF link: https://poly.googleusercontent.com/downloads/3N5cUYDN30g/d_IjPXhvbsO/Hi-fi%20stereo.gltf

---

Google poly is able to preview all models using [this](https://www.gstatic.com/external_hosted/threejs-r89/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js) loader and they are using three.js r-89 GLTF loader to render models on their view check the links above.

Comment: Are You sure those are glTF2.0 ? As noted in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html), You can use glTF1.0 only with this [loader](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders). Did You try it out on Your model ?

Comment: Yes, all of them are 2.0.
They are converted from OBJ to GLTF using Obj2GltfConverter. 
I found this code in all GLTF files.
"asset": {
    "generator": "Obj2GltfConverter",
    "version": "2.0"
  },

Comment: The files work in A-Frame for me. Please try to include enough information in your question to reproduce the problem (i.e. a demo or minimal code) as there could be many reasons a particular model isn't visible, per [troubleshooting docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/models.html#troubleshooting). I'll answer with likely causes below, but these are just guesses without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible causes here, it's best to include a JSFiddle or minimal code to reproduce the problem for this reason. Likely issues in this case:

1. Use a local server when developing offline.
2. Models often need to be scaled down. In this case, the stereo model should be scaled down to `scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"` or so.
3. The URLs you mention are meant for download, not for hosting the model. Trying to use them within a scene will give CORS errors, so you need to download them first, including the `*.bin` files associated.

Also refer to the [A-Frame troubleshooting docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/models.html#troubleshooting) for help diagnosing issues. I tested the stereo model after addressing these issues:

[image]

Comment: Oh my god! they are scaled way too much by default.

Is there any way to actually scale models to a certain length so that its visible in the view. The app I am trying to make actually takes the poly links and just adds them up to their original sizes.

It would be nice if users can actually see every model scaled to a standard size or if there is a way I can get the current size in a unit so I can scale them after adding?

Comment: You could write a component that scales models to a consistent size, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d) for some details or feel free to ask a new question if you get stuck.