# How to find intersection of objects in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I load 20 objects which have random position. I need to make it so that the objects have random position but don't intersect.
How to fint the intersection of thee objects and check intersection?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        // Create a material
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var map = textureLoader.load('./models/test_2.png');
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: map });

        var shipMtl = new MTLLoader();
        var loader = new this.THREE.OBJLoader();

        shipMtl.load('./models/test.mtl', function(materials) {
            materials.preload();

            loader.setMaterials(materials);
            loader.load('./models/test.obj', function(object) {
                object.traverse(function(node) {
                    if (node.isMesh) node.material = material;
                });

                object.position.x = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                object.scale.x = Math.random() * 2 + 40;
                object.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 40;
                object.scale.z = Math.random() * 2 + 40;
                object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                var obj = object; // put your object as global
                scene.add(obj);
            });
        });
    }

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.refs.figure.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: If you need 20 of the same object just load it once and use `.clone()` to attach it multiple times at different positions. For "intersections" you can [compute a bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d) and try a new random position if bounding boxes overlap.

Comment: Or compute a bounding sphere and do the same things.

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the question properly but this is the function that check that if two object intersect or not

```
    function checkTwoShapeIntersect(object1,object2){
    /**
     * This function check if two object3d intersect or not
     * @param {THREE.Object3D} object1
     * @param {THREE.Object3D} object2
     * @returns {Boolean} 
    */ 

    // Check for intersection using bounding box intersection test
    let bBox1 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object1);
    let bBox2 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object2);

    const intersection = bBox1.intersectsBox(bBox2);
    // const intersection = mesh1.geometry.boundingBox.intersectsBox(mesh2.geometry.boundingBox);

    if (intersection) { // The shape geometries intersect.
        return true
    } else { // The shape geometries do not intersect.
        return false
    }
}
```